# as3 BitmapData threshold, what happens to pixels that fail the test? How to remove them?

Tags: actionscript-3, pixel, bitmapdata, threshold

When i use bitmapdata threshold, what happens to the pixels that fail the threshold test?
As per my observation they remain as in, so is there any way to remove them?

Comment: do another threshold with replacement color of 0x00000000 (ie: zero alpha)

Comment: @LeeBurrows This would work if a threshold color would be within the threshold, aka calling the same threshold will not alter the bitmap further. But it's possible that the color passed into `BitmapData.threshold()` will be naturally outside the threshold, thus this approach will nullify the entire bitmap.

Comment: @Vesper. Netrus could reverse the condition on second threshold to affect the other set of pixels. ie: if first threshold was using ">" then second ones uses "<"

Comment: @LeeBurrows Yes, but it's not enough. Say you have a bitmap consisting of two colors, 0x305070ff and 0xaaaaaaaa. You want a threshold of alpha greater than 0x80 to turn into 0x55ff0000. So, you call `threshold()` and have a BitmapData of two colors, 0x305070ff and 0x55ff0000. Now you want to nullify all the other pixels, you call threshold with reversed operation and BAM, all your bitmapdata now consists of zeroes! That's not what you normally want, right?

Comment: thnx guys! :D bt making a temporary bitmap for copying the threshold that passed the test worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a temporary (static, reusable) transparent BitmapData for this operation. You fill it with 0x0, then call `threshold()` setting source to your BitmapData, and `copySource` flag set to false, then you `copyPixels()` back with `mergeAlpha` set to false.

```
var tbd:BitmapData=yourBitmapData.clone(); // this makes a new BitmapData, so be warned
var p0:Point=new Point();
tbd.fillRect(tbd.rect,0);
tbd.threshold(yourBitmapData,yourBitmapData.rect,p0,yourOperation,
    yourThreshold,yourColor,yourMask,false);
yourBitmapData.copyPixels(tbd,tbd.rect,p0);
tbd.dispose();
```